# Remove everything except numbers and alphabets from a string using google sheet or excel formulas

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have search but found python and related solutions.

I have a string like

> "Hello 'how' are % you?"

which I want to convert to below after Remove everything except numbers and alphabets

> Hello how are you

I am using Regexreplace as follows but now sure what should be the replacement or if its a right approach

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2 , "([^A-Za-z0-9]+)")
```

The main thing i want to remove from the string are the stuff like " or strange symbols

can anyone help?

Comment: Note, Excel and GS are looking similar but are actually very different apps. Please pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B2,"[\W_]+"," "))
```

Or, include the space in your character class:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"[\W_ ]+"," "))
```

Where: `\W` is short for `[^A-Ba-b0-9_]`, so to include the underscore we added it to the character class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "'|%|""", ))
```

[image]